# Android app crashes as i try to use kSoap2

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap2

Hi im new to Android development.. Sorry.

My Android App crashes as i am trying to use kSoap2 to connect the app to a web service:
My Error log is as follows:

```
2-05 12:48:05.100: E/dalvikvm(749): Could not find class 'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject', referenced from method com.example.mytestws.MainActivity.onCreate
12-05 12:48:05.100: W/dalvikvm(749): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 548 (Lorg/ksoap2/serialization/SoapObject;) in Lcom/example/mytestws/MainActivity;
12-05 12:48:05.100: D/dalvikvm(749): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0012
12-05 12:48:05.100: D/dalvikvm(749): VFY: dead code 0x0014-0057 in Lcom/example/mytestws/MainActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
12-05 12:48:05.250: D/AndroidRuntime(749): Shutting down VM
12-05 12:48:05.250: W/dalvikvm(749): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
12-05 12:48:05.261: E/AndroidRuntime(749): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-05 12:48:05.261: E/AndroidRuntime(749): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject
12-05 12:48:05.261: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at com.example.mytestws.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:29)
12-05 12:48:05.261: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-05 12:48:05.261: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
12-05 12:48:05.261: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-05 12:48:05.261: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-05 12:48:05.261: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-05 12:48:05.261: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-05 12:48:05.261: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-05 12:48:05.261: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-05 12:48:05.261: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-05 12:48:05.261: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-05 12:48:05.261: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-05 12:48:05.261: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-05 12:48:05.261: E/AndroidRuntime(749):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: It says no class definition error, eclipse cant find org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject, it is probably missing frommanifest or you made a mistake when you added it to your proj case it is a library or external jar

Comment: Make sure that  kSoap2 is added as refrence library to your project

Comment: @najjaseven accept the answer it is has helped you

Comment: @frayab can you please take a look at this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719386/web-service-provides-output-error-when-i-access-it-through-android-instead-of

Comment: @vodich can you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719386/web-service-provides-output-error-when-i-access-it-through-android-instead-of and help me out! thanks

Comment: @HusamA.Al-ahmadi can you please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719386/web-service-provides-output-error-when-i-access-it-through-android-instead-of and help me out.. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add ksoap2 library to your classpath as an external library and also copy the .jar into libs folder of the project.

Comment: can you please take a look at the following link and let me know the problem that im having now pls.. Thanks!http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13719386/web-service-provides-output-error-when-i-access-it-through-android-instead-of